# Show that set of $2 \times 2$ non-zero matrices over rationals does not form a ring

Tags: ring-theory

Show that set of $2 \times 2$ non-zero matrices over rationals does not form a ring under matrix addition and multiplication.

I am not able to see why this set won't be a ring. $(R,+)$ forms an abelian group. Associative and distributive property holds in $R$. So $(R,+,\times)$ should be a ring. Am i missing something ?

Comment: **non-zero** <- there

Comment: @DanielFischer Since that gave the OP his/her eureka moment, it's worth posting as an answer. Please ping me if you do put it up!

Comment: For people reading this: after reading Daniel's comment, the OP posted a comment like "oh of course now I see!" which was consequently deleted, probably because it contained profanity. I would like to imagine that Archimedes also added such things to his "eureka!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a word in the problem statement:

> Show that set of $2\times 2$ **non-zero** matrices over rationals does not form a ring under matrix addition and multiplication.

That makes the difference, the set contains no additive identity (and isn't even closed under addition or multiplication).

Comment: if instead of "non-zero", the question says "rational" will it form a ring then ?

Comment: Yes, the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with entries in a ring, with the operations of matrix addition and matrix multiplication forms a ring. To get something that is not a ring, you must remove some matrices so that at least one of the axioms fails to hold.

Comment: sorry, i again missed a word. the question wants me to prove that the set of all $2x2$ non-singular matrices over rationals is not a ring. I cant see why that will not be a ring. It should even have inverse.

Comment: The zero matrix is not non-singular. The sum of two non-singular matrices need not be non-singular (consider $A + (-A)$).

Comment: oh !! Thank you very much for that. I was missing this point.